# Storing string in resource,

Tags: windows, string, resources

Does anyone know a method other than string table to store strings in resource..
cause i would like to store only one or two string ...and avoid string table as if i use FindResource() function it will load a whole block of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store each string separately as a Binary resource. In this case you can load each string separately by its ID.

Code below will extract resource with "ResId" from "RES_SECTION", where
RES_SECTION is custom section defined by user when resource is added, and
ResId is id of the resource.

```
HMODULE hModule     = NULL;
HGLOBAL hResource   = NULL;
HRSRC   hResInfo    = NULL;
LPVOID  tmpData     = NULL;
DWORD   tmpDataSize = 0;

/* find and get resource handle */
hResInfo = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ResId), RES_SECTION);

/* loads resource into global memory. */
hResource = LoadResource(hModule, hResInfo);

/* get a pointer to the loaded resource */
tmpData = LockResource(hResource);

/* determine the size of the resource */
tmpDataSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResInfo);

unsigned char * str = new unsigned char[tmpDataSize];

memcpy_s(str, tmpDataSize, tmpData, tmpDataSize);
```

Do not forget to add correct error handling for above function calls.

Comment: thanks a lot friend..you helped a lot god bless yew but this code is for resource extracting...what about storing how to store as binary

Comment: my code is almost same but my string is stored in string table so it doesnt works it is unable to findresource()